# LSTM Model Structure with Low Arena Size for TensorflowLite

Tags: lstm, esp32, tensorflow-lite, tinyml

I'm working on my project with Time Series Forecasting on ESP32. Seem like my model arena size is too big for ESP32 to predict the value.

I have tried optimize it based on the TensorflowLite document to lower the size. However, I still can't predict with my ESP32. It keeps printing 0.

Here is my colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17Ip0dvavjme9c4oDF7lzte6-uRqRlzq9?usp=sharing

For ESP32. I use EloquentTinyML library to deploy the model

I am really new to this stuff so if you have any solution please let me know. Thank you!